# how to insert Arabic text to oracle database?

Tags: php, html, character-encoding, oracle11g

I have html + php application connected to oracle database 11g. I am trying to insert Arabic characters via form, The issue it shows "????"

I surfed the internet to find a solution, and I did almost every trick but nothing works until now!! please I am disparate for help!

**My environment:**

- Windows 7 home premium
- html charset is set to utf8 ( I tried windows-1256, windows-1252 also did not work)
- registry NLS_LANG is set to  AMERICAN_AMERICA.AR8MSWIN1256
- oracle 11g the table columns are set to NVARCHAR2
- oracle character set is WE8MSWIN1252

**Note:** Arabic characters **displays correctly** when data is inserted via **SQL DEVELOPER**, knowing that SQL Developer encoding is set to **windows-1256**

Thanks

**EDIT:**
I changed oracle character set to al32utf8, and still same issue!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the database charset to UTF-8.
This is the closest to the source so maybe it should be working then.

Comment: but why it works when i use sql developer!? that means the problem is in the html + php side.. i tried changing html charset still no hope.. its driving me crazy!!